# Special char change in email body content

Tags: email, character-encoding

I am sending a report link to user through email all code works fine and email link like this

```
www.xyz.com/FeedbackReport.aspx?RequestId=ede0e23e-699b-4905-bfbb-698081ba6b18&ÆÆÆÆ=2979
```

but in email it is changed to

```
www.xyz.com/FeedbackReport.aspx?RequestId=ede0e23e-699b-4905-bfbb-698081ba6b18&%C3%86%C3%86%C3%86%C3%86=2979
```

I want to send original link text in email but Ii am not getting how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the character encoding in URL, check [this character encoding reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp):

```
Ã   %C3
```

*URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.

Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.

URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.
URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a + sign.*

I would suggest you to use characters, which are not encoded in URL

Comment: can you tell me some special char. which are not encoded in URL

Comment: As I already pointed out, ASCII printable character sets can be used - _http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp_